# Selenium: How can I find the correct command for add_arguments()?

Tags: python, selenium-chromedriver, google-chrome-devtools

I am using selenium python and chrome driver and wanted to know if there is any way you can get the command to enable or disable options in add_arguments() function. For example, there are '--disable-infobars', etc., but if I come across a new setting, how do I find its appropriate command?
An example being the settings to auto-download pdfs.
Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

Chromium has lots of command switches, such as `--disable-extensions` or `--disable-popup-blocking` that can be enabled at runtime using `Options().add_argument()`

Here is a list of some of the [Chromium Command Line Switches](https://peter.sh/experiments/chromium-command-line-switches/).

Chromium also allows for other runtime enabled features, such as `useAutomationExtension` or `plugins.always_open_pdf_externally.` These features are enabled using `DesiredCapabilities.`

I normal review the [source code](https://github.com/chromium/chromium) for Chromium when I need to find find other features to control with `DesiredCapabilities.`

The code below uses both command switches and runtime enabled features to automatically save a PDF file to disk without being prompted.

For my answer I downloaded a PDF file from the Library of Congress.

If you have any questions related to this code or something else related to your question please let me know.

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
from selenium.webdriver.common.desired_capabilities import DesiredCapabilities

chrome_options = Options()
chrome_options.add_argument('--disable-infobars')
chrome_options.add_argument('--start-maximized')
chrome_options.add_argument('--disable-extensions')
chrome_options.add_argument('--disable-popup-blocking')

# disable the banner "Chrome is being controlled by automated test software"
chrome_options.add_experimental_option("useAutomationExtension", False)
chrome_options.add_experimental_option("excludeSwitches", ['enable-automation'])


# you can set the path for your download_directory
prefs = {
    'download.default_directory': 'download_directory',
    'download.prompt_for_download': False,
    'plugins.always_open_pdf_externally': True
}

capabilities = DesiredCapabilities().CHROME
chrome_options.add_experimental_option('prefs', prefs)
capabilities.update(chrome_options.to_capabilities())

driver = webdriver.Chrome('/usr/local/bin/chromedriver', options=chrome_options)

url_main = 'https://www.loc.gov/aba/publications/FreeLCC/freelcc.html'

driver.get(url_main)

driver.implicitly_wait(20)

download_pdf_file = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="main_body"]/ul[2]/li[1]/a')
download_pdf_file.click()
```

Answer (score 1):

You can add options arguments to a chromium webdriver using Python the following way:

```
    options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()

    # Arguments go below
    options.add_argument("--no-sandbox")
    options.add_argument("--disable-gpu")
    options.add_argument("--window-size=800,600")
    options.add_argument("--disable-dev-shm-usage")
    options.add_argument("--user-agent={}".format("your user agent string"))
    # Etc etc..

    options.binary_location = "absolute/path/to/chrome.exe"
    driver = webdriver.Chrome(
        desired_capabilities=caps,
        executable_path="absolute/path/to/chromium-driver.exe",
        options=options,
    )
```

[Here you can find the list of all the supported arguments](https://peter.sh/experiments/chromium-command-line-switches/) for chrome.